# DecimalFormat в Android глюк

Tags: java, android

```
DecimalFormat myFo = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###");
```

Данная строчка парсит double переменую и выводит ее в форме ###,###.###.

```
    Например:
    double d = 121123.045

    Результат будет:
    123 123,054
```

Обратите внимание на запятую. Дело в том, что Android при математических операциях над числами не хочет воспринимать ее и выводит ошибку.

**Вопрос**: как справиться с этим глюком? Переписать DecimalFormat? А проще?

Comment: Не совсем понял, в чём проблема то? Насколько я вижу, результат соответствует заданному формату.

Answer (score 4):

Причина, как верно указал [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) в локали. В нашей локали разделителем тысяч служит пробел, в десятичной дроби запятая.

Так что это никакой не глюк, а штатное поведение форматтера. Попробуйте в телефоне поменять локаль на аглицкую и вывод сразу же изменится.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, человек хочет, что бы разделителем в результате была точка. Он ведь в формате "задал точку"!

[@tsvik dima](/users/14603/tsvik-dima) DecimalFormat - это для отображения пользователю. А для расчетов строковое представление не нужно. К тому же, помните, что в разных странах разделители целой и дробной - различны.

Comment: а вот арабские страны применяют моммайе (это что-то похожее на запятую)

Answer (score 1):

```
 DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern,dfs);
```

И будет тебе счастье :)